# Html with css @media max-width not working

Tags: html, css

When using brackets to code my website, the @media worked and would make divs appear and disappear to support mobile screens. But after uploading to my hosting site, it does not work and all the elements are showing at once. How can I fix this? The relevant CSS code is below.

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width : 720px) {
    .disappear {
        display: none;
    }
    #menuposition {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .galleryitem {
        width: 100%
    }
    .containergallery {
        max-width: 250px;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }
}
@media (min-width : 721px) {
    .reappear {
        display: none;
    }
    #menuposition {
        right: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
@media (max-width : 960px) {
    .galleryitem {
        width:100%
    }
    .containergallery {
        max-width: 300px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize that, in brackets it was linked to the correct css which did contain the code I sent you. So in the local preview it looked fine. So I saved it as a new file and relinked it and now it works. Thanks again. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page you linked to doesn't have that CSS in the source anywhere and none of the linked files have it either.

Link the CSS to the page or place it in an inline-style element.